# Can I retrieve the position of some specified text on the pdf page for subsequent use?

Tags: positioning, text, horizontal

I'm working on a text in LaTeX (I have TeXLive 2017 installed on my system), and it would really be of great help if there was any way to "save" the horizontal position of a word (either the beginning, the midpoint, or the end of that word) in such a way that, if I want to, I can start the next line from the horizontal position I saved.

The following example produces what I mean:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tabto}

\begin{document}
\noindent What I'd like to do is the following: I'm writing something, then I make a jump
\newline
\noindent\phantom{jump} from the end of last word
\newline
\noindent\phantom{jump from the end of last wo}or the midpoint
\newline
\noindent\phantom{jump from the end of last woor the }or the beginning of it
\end{document}
```

Obviously I first had to `pdflatex` the file, then discover that the second line in the output pdf file begins with the word "jump", then get back to my .tex file, do a `\nextline` and phantom out the word "jump" before typing "from the end of last word", then `pdflatex` the file again, and so on.

What I would really like to be able to do is to define a command (or to use it, if it is already there) so that, within a couple of `pdflatex` executions, I obtain the same result with something like the following:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tabto}

\begin{document}
\noindent What I'd like to do is the following: I'm writing something, then I make a \xendsave{jump}{\xPosTag}
\newline
\noindent \xskipto{\xPosTag} from the end of last \xmidsave{word}{\xPosTag}
\newline
\noindent \xskipto{\xPosTag} or the \xbeginsave{midpoint}{\xPosTag}
\newline
\noindent \xskipto{\xPosTag} or the beginning of it
\end{document}
```

Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated :)
Thank you in advance

Federico

**Edit**: As per suggestion, I used the `zref` package, along with `tabto` (which I used in order to skip to the saved x-position) and `xfp` (for calculations).

Here is what I managed to accomplish:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tabto}

\usepackage[savepos]{zref}
\usepackage{xfp}

\newcommand{\xsptolinepospt}[1]{
  \fpeval{#1/65536.-(1in+\hoffset+\oddsidemargin)}
}
\newcommand{\xcapoend}[1]{ 
  #1\zsaveposx{xendtag}
  \newline
  \noindent \tabto{\xsptolinepospt{\zposx{xendtag}} pt}
}
\newcommand{\xcapobegin}[1]{ 
  \zsaveposx{xbegintag}#1
  \newline
  \noindent \tabto{\xsptolinepospt{\zposx{xbegintag}} pt}
}
\newcommand{\xcapomiddle}[1]{ 
  \zsaveposx{xbegintagg}#1\zsaveposx{xendtagg}
  \newline
  \noindent \tabto{\xsptolinepospt{ \fpeval{ 0.5*(\zposx{xbegintagg}+\zposx{xendtagg})} } pt}
}

\begin{document}
\noindent What I'd like to do is the following: I'm writing something, 
then I make a \xcapoend{jump}from 
the end of last\xcapomiddle{word}or 
the\xcapobegin{midpoint}or the beginning of it
\end{document}
```

Not much elegance in my code.
However, it works; it requires me to `pdflatex` the file several times before converging to the desired result, which, once I saw it happen, I think is to be expected due to how `zsavepos` works (as far as I could understand).

Comment: se `\pdfsavepos` (lots of examples on this site)

Comment: the zref package has savepos module.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I thought you'd recommend `\tikzmark`, given your predilection for all thing TikZ.

Comment: @AndrewStacey I have  gold badge so know it's the same thing really:-)

Comment: I guess the difficult bit is more figuring out which word or words should be remembered - is there a rule for that?

Comment: Thank you all, I managed to use zref :)